# How to restore postgresql database from .txt.gz file?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I'm using pgAdmin 4 and i want to restore my old database backup file which is in txt.gz format.

I've tried using pgAdmin  to restore but getting error message like:

> pg_restore: [archiver] input file does not appear to be a valid archive

Comment: Have you tried to unzip the file and then simply copy its contents into the SQL Script window and run them ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please try with below command

```
gunzip -c filename.gz | psql dbname
```